# Ng-bind showing undefined in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I've got an MVC project with AngularJS. In my controller I'd like `$scope.userRole` to display a string `Admin` if the user is an Admin. I've tried to solve this with `ng-bind` but it returns `undefined` for `$scope.data.admin` in my `if-statement`

```
@if (User.IsInRole("Admin")
{
    <div ng-Controller="ctrl" ng-bind="data.admin" >
        @Html.Partial("AdminPartial")
    </div
}
```

And my AngularJS:

```
$scope.userRole = "";
$scope.data = {};
if ($scope.data.admin != null && $scope.data.admin != "") {
    $scope.userRole = "Admin";
} else {
    $scope.userRole = "User";
}
```

`$scope.data.admin` is undefined and I don't know why. I should add that I'm fairly new to AngularJS

Comment: `ng-model` doesn't work on div, you should have a input type of element to assign `ng-model`

Comment: You also missed a "=" between the ng-model and value.

Comment: @Rakeschand Is there another way to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot bind `ng-model` to a `div`. Use `ng-bind` instead

```
<div ng-Controller="ctrl" ng-bind="data.admin" ></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`ngModel` can basically bind with `input`, `select` and `textarea` see [ngModel](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel)

Answer (score 0):

You are using `ng-model` on a div which is not possible. If you want a two-way binding you should use an `input` or `textarea` or `checkbox` or ... something where the user can interact.

In your case, it seems that your are looking for a one-way binding (Only display the value of the variable) then you should use `{{variable}}` or `ng-bind`

```
@if (User.IsInRole("Admin")
{
    <div ng-Controller="ctrl" ng-bind="data.admin" >
        @Html.Partial("AdminPartial")
    </div
}
```

OR you want to display the `div` is the user is admin.. then you should use `ng-if`

```
@if (User.IsInRole("Admin")
{
    <div ng-Controller="ctrl" ng-if="data.admin" >
        @Html.Partial("AdminPartial")
    </div
}
```

Comment: This still returns `undefined` for `$scope.data.admin` in the Angular controller

Comment: Are you initializing `$scope.data.admin` ?

Comment: You should have this somewhere : `$scope.data.admin = false;` and it must be set to the right value somewhere

Comment: I've tried initiate `$scope.data = { admin: false };` and then use an `ng-init="data.admin = 'true'"` but it's still `false` in the controller. What I really want is to have access to a string depending on if the user is in the admin role.

Comment: You should not use `ng-init` to define the value of the admin. Where do you get this value ? When do you want to say it is true or false ? You should create a function inside the controller

Comment: When an admin is logged in I want to have the controller set the value of `$scope.userRole` to the string `admin`. I need that string in another function in my controller. I can't seem that to work with ng-bind the way I understand it. It seems like it should be easily done

Comment: I think  that you should learn the basic of AngularJS. You seem to misunderstand every directive. You should have a function that is called when the userRole changes and you should assign the value you want in your controller